Unable to print marathi words in the PDF
In my MERN stack web application not able to print the Marathi words,It is printing like "DDDDD DDDDDDD DDDDDDD" I have used Devanagari font and bellow is my code
const generatePDF = (reportData) => {
        const doc = new jsPDF();

        // Add logo image
        const logoWidth = 30;  // Width of the logo
        const logoHeight = 30; // Height of the logo
        doc.addImage(logo, 'JPEG', 20, 20, logoWidth, logoHeight);

        // Set starting X and Y positions for text after logo
        const startX = logoWidth + 40;
        const startY = 20;

        // Add title and report details
        doc.setFontSize(18);
        doc.text('हे एक मराठी शीर्षक आहे ', startX, startY); //This is not printing as expected in my PDF
        doc.setFontSize(14);
        doc.text('Operator Wise Reports', startX, startY + 10);
        doc.text(`Operator Name: ${(selectedOperator)}`, startX, startY + 20);
        doc.text(`Report Date: ${new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-IN', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })}`, startX, startY + 30);

        const columns = [
            { title: 'Donner Name', dataKey: 'name' },
            { title: 'Donation Date', dataKey: 'date' },
            { title: 'Receipt Type', dataKey: 'type' },
            { title: 'Payment Mode', dataKey: 'paymentMode' },
            { title: 'Amount', dataKey: 'amount' }
        ];

        const rows = reportData.map(report => ({
            type: report.type,
            amount: report.amount,
            date: new Date(report.date).toLocaleDateString('en-IN', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }),
            name: report.name,
            paymentMode: report.paymentMode
        }));

        doc.autoTable({
            head: [columns.map(col => col.title)],
            body: rows.map(row => columns.map(col => row[col.dataKey])),
            startY: 60,
        });

        doc.save('daily_receipt_reports.pdf');
    };

I tried my libraries of react and also tried different Devanagari fonts but issue didn't resolved
